# how to convert a query result which in a string format to csv in python

Tags: python, csv, hive

How to convert a query result from hive which has been read using stdout.read() to a csv or more presentable format.

As im reading from hive I don’t get column headers and data will be a string like below:

`-3056    2018-03-29  143444  11  0.84    51  0.95    60046-5065  0.99    2000    2   4   109736873   2019-04-02 06:53:54 2019-04-02 06:53:54 I   109736873   Y   105586013`

Tried to delimit using spaces but didn’t help much. As the no of columns will be dynamic based on situations.

reading from hive:

````
for p in processes: 
            p.wait()
            output = output + ' ' + p.stdout.read()
            error_data = p.stderr.read()```

trying to parse to csv:

with open("mismatch.csv",'wb') as f:
                    w = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='/n')
                    for line in validate_result:
                            w.writerow(line)```
````

Comment: Any reason its read as stdout.read() from Hive, instead of query or exporting hive data to CSV with column names ?

Comment: @GaneshChandrasekaran the code already exists , which I cant change.

Comment: Not sure whats inside  'validate_result'  list item.. but can you try write as JSON file.. which gives you the flexibility of  number of columns.  

Hope you have some info on datatype to keep  "key"  consistent for json.

Comment: all i get is the query result i.e type string in validate_result